# Show % in PivotTable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in which I want to show on time delivery %:

[image: SO26642184 question example]

My "on time lines count" is the total amount of lines I have shipped on time.  The total lines count is the total lines count regardless if it has shipped on time or not.  For example my on time delivery % on month 1 should be 79.8% which is 1227/1537.

How can I get this to show inside of my pivot table.

Comment: Can you show how your source data is structured? That will determine how to set up your PivotTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Calculated Field with Formula:

```
=On Time Lines Count / Total Lines Count
```

Comment: I don't want to do that, because If I do, then everytime I refresh the data, it causes my formulas to move up or down and then gives me errors.

Comment: I looked at the links you provided.  I don't see PivotTable Tools > Options > Tools - Formulas, Calculated Field. I don't see options under my pivot table.  The options I do see to the far left doesn't have a tool selection under it.  By looking at what the link, that seems to be exactly what I need, I just can't find it on my excel.

Comment: Hey pnuts. I found it.  For me it's under Pivot Table Options --> Fields,Items, & Sets --> Calculated Field.  So this worked for me once I found out where it was.  Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

If I were in that situation, I'd probably put a formula like the following all the way down Col D (assuming the pivot table is in cols A:C):

> =if(c6="","",b6/c6)

That will show the percentage you want where it is relevant and empty cells elsewhere, and will continue to do so when the pivot table is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of your PivotTable, you can create a calculated field and format as a percentage, this will work, I reproduce your example and it worked...

Link example

[Mega](https://mega.co.nz/#!i4xSgKxZ!d8INw1P2y9-mH5kFgWSTCTzkaAZDowDZ7ouRkOu0H40)

Comment: I can't access Mega at work.  Is there another way to provide the example?